# Greping text after match with slashes

Tags: grep

So, I need to grep the text after a string like

```
Motherboard P/N           :   XXXXXXXXXX
```

Where `XXXXXXXXX` is the text I want.
I don't want the `Motherboard P/N           :`

I can't seem to make awk, cut, sed or anything work well with the P/N

Any ideas?

Comment: did you escape the / writing something like \/ instaed of the fwd-slash? This might solve the issue, hopefully.  Please have a little crash course in RegEx (Regular Expressions). This might be cumbersome for some minutes but a mighty big step forward in controlling CLI stuff :-)  As steeldriver told: We can not do much w/o more info how and where and with what tools you tried what activity. Obvious?

Comment: Sorry:  I just need everything after the :
The command will output a number of lines with Motherboard xxx :  yyyyy
Like Motherboard S/N :  2345678980
Motherboard P/N  : asdfghjk
Motherboard type : dfghjk

I just want the stuff after Motherboard P/N :

Comment: \/ makes sense, I'll try and come back

Comment: THANKS, RegEx tutorial starting now.  Thanks opinion_no9

Comment: I love this corner of the internet: TLDP. For the specific question you will find answers here: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/regexp.html      at least I hope so.

Answer (score 4):

```
grep -oP 'Motherboard P/N           :   \K.*'
```

Explanation:

- `-o` Print only matching part of the line
- `-P` Use Perl-compatible regex (PCRE) - this enables more advanced regex features
- `\K` Don't consider the preceding as part of the match.
- `.*` Match zero or more of any character (except a newline)

Answer (score 0):

Why not using the pipeline mechanism with grep and sed in the following way:

```
grep "Motherboard P/N" souceFile | sed 's/^.*Motherboard\ P\/N\ \:\ //1'
```

where sourceFile is a file containing your text. Sed has the following regular expression:

- `^.*` means: from the beginning of the line, any number of characters till
- `Motherboard` string with some more characters, which need a comment (below)
- `\` character in front of special characters "escapes" them, so they are not interpreted by the shell or the command, but instead are used as plain characters: a space, slash and colon.

Or you could pipe the output of a command (like the useful `sudo lshw`)

```
sudo lshw | grep "Motherboard P/N" | sed 's/^.*Motherboard\ P\/N\ \:\ //1'
```

However, it's most likely that you will not find "Motherboard P/N : " text in the output of lshw, and the output of this example may be empty...

EDIT:

Or, as I see what you need from your comments, you could modify the regex slightly, to accommodate to "S/N" and "P/N" at the same time.  Use a dot `.` in place of a character that varies between the source text lines. E.g.:

```
sed 's/^.*Motherboard\ P\/N\ \:\ //1'  # the initial version
sed 's/^.*Motherboard\ .\/N\ \:\ //1'  # dot instead of "P"
```

...the same for `grep`

Answer (score 0):

Just use look-back with grep:

```
grep -argument '(?<=string_you_use_as_separator)what_you_are_looking_for' dir/file_to_be_grepd.txt
```

in this case regex would look like this:

```
(?<=:)\w*
```

the full grep command. use `-o` to neglect everything you don't need and `-P` for pearl regex. And i like to pipe it into sort just for good measure

```
grep -oP '(?<=:)\w*' file.txt | sort
```